# Testing Activity with a Fragment with Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I want to check if the `Activity` I create in a test is showing a `Fragment`. How can I do this? I've tried searching through Stack Overflow and Google but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I dont know how it works but you can test if a fragment is attached to an activity with isAdded() if it helps you somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the fragment by id with

```
activity.getFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_container);
```

If this returns something different from `null`, then it means that your container has a `Fragment`.

Comment: If this is the final solution, consider marking this post as answer.

Comment: It says I have to wait 2 days before accepting my own answer :P