# Unit testing Android Tab Layout

Tags: android, robolectric

I am new to Android Unit testing and trying to write some test cases for Android tab layout with `Robolectric`. I am able to verify the tab count and tab titles. But I am not able to verify some content in tabs. Can anyone help me in getting the fragment content and verify some elements in that?

Here is my code

```
public void verifyTabsDefaultText() throws Exception{
    ViewPager viewPager = searchActivity.findViewById(R.id.container);
    FragmentPagerAdapter tabAdapter = (FragmentPagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter();

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    TextView hintTextView = tabAdapter.getItem(0).getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_hint_text_view);

    assertTrue(hintTextView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);

}
```

`tabAdapter.getItem(0)` is giving `null` value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811580/testing-activity-with-a-fragment-with-robolectric

Comment: @AlexHart Thanks for the reply. The link which you shared is about normal fragments. But I am trying to get the fragment from FragmentPagerAdapter object which is attached to tab layout. Could you please check my updated question with my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import static junit.framework.Assert.*;

@RunWith(WithTestDefaultsRunner.class)
public class ViewPagerTest {

private ViewPager pager;
private TestPagerAdapter adapter;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    pager = new ViewPager(new Activity());
    adapter = new TestPagerAdapter();
}

@Test
public void shouldSetAndGetAdapter() throws Exception {
    assertNull(pager.getAdapter());

    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    assertSame(adapter, pager.getAdapter());
}

@Test
public void test_getAndSetCurrentItem() throws Exception {
    pager.setCurrentItem(2);
    assertEquals(2, pager.getCurrentItem());
}

@Test
public void setCurrentItem_shouldInvokeListener() throws Exception {
    TestOnPageChangeListener listener = new TestOnPageChangeListener();
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(listener);
    assertFalse(listener.onPageSelectedCalled);
    pager.setCurrentItem(2);
    assertTrue(listener.onPageSelectedCalled);
}

private static class TestPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return false;
    }
}

private static class TestOnPageChangeListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {
    public boolean onPageSelectedCalled;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        onPageSelectedCalled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am facing issue while getting the content from the fragment pager adapter which is attached to tab layout. I have updated my question with my code. Could you please check now?

Comment: @Kameswari I had update my code with Fragment Pager adapter, can you please check now?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sample. But my requirement is to verify some UI elements in the fragment. I am trying to get it from pager adapter. But I am getting null value.

Comment: @Kameswari I understood your requirement, you need to set up pager & adapter using the above sample and then only you can verify UI element.

Comment: could you please let me know which gradle library I have to include to get com.xtremelabs.robolectric.WithTestDefaultsRunner class?

Comment: com.xtremelabs.robolectric.WithTestDefaultsRunner its own class You can take exmple from here https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/25270445/#

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is probably not the answer you were looking for but you shouldn't write normal unit tests for android related classes/views. What you should do is writing instrumented unit tests(or you can call it ui tests) which runs on real android devices (or emulators) where you have access to the android related classes, current activity(context) view elements without doing any tricks. And the framework, Espresso makes it really easy to execute such a test.

Using espresso, you can write

```
 onView(withId(thatWillOpenPageIWant)).perform(click())
onView(withId(R.id.search_hint_text_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

Or you can insert any other condition you want inside matches.

One important thing, android has two different directories, namely `test and androidTest`

Your normal unit tests should be under the folder test (you cannot reach to android related classes under this directory) and your instrumented unit tests should reside under `androidTest`.

To learn more about [espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to implement one test case with espresso and when I tried to run, its giving error like "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation." Could you please tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: This may happen because of multiple reasons. You should ask this (preferably search this because it is a common error) with your gradle file. My guess would be you tried to write your ui test under the test folder, instead of androidTest folder hence you get this error. As I stated in my answer ui tests should be under the androidTest folder

Answer (score 0):

This is my code that I wrote for unit testing a `ViewPager` having **swipable fragments**. There are some custom classes I made for my program but that won't be a problem. You'll get a pretty solid idea to continue with your code:

PS. This is an [Instrumentation test](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests). These tests are essentially used to test Android Specific Functionality like UI and classes like `ViewPager` (used here).

```
package com.example.onboardingfold;

import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario;
import androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.example.onboardingfold.fragment.OnboardingPage1Fragment;
import com.example.onboardingfold.fragment.adapter.MyCustomFragmentPagerAdapter;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;

import static androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getContext;
import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertSame;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    ActivityScenario activityScenario;
    private ViewPager testPager;
    private OnboardingPage1Fragment fragment = new OnboardingPage1Fragment();

    // Intiate the viewPager and PagerAdapter
    @Before
    public void init_ViewPager() {
        testPager = new ViewPager(getContext());
        fragment = (OnboardingPage1Fragment) OnboardingPage1Fragment.newInstance(1);
    }

    // Create a Mock Object of the Custom FragmentPagerAdapter
    @Mock
    MyCustomFragmentPagerAdapter testAdapter = new MyCustomFragmentPagerAdapter(fragment.getFragmentManager());

    // Check for proper instantiation of the viewPager PagerAdapter
    @Test
    public void test_InitAdapter() {
        assertNull(testPager.getAdapter());

        testPager.setAdapter(testAdapter);
        assertSame(testAdapter, testPager.getAdapter());
    }

    // Testing for Adapter NOT_NULL
    @Test
    public void test_AdapterNotNull() {
        assertNotNull(testAdapter);
    }

    // Testing for TabLayout and ViewPager being displayed
    @Test
    public void test_PagerDisplayed() {
        activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity.class);
        onView(withId(R.id.onboardingViewPager)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.tab_layout)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

This is my `CustomFragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
package com.example.onboardingfold.fragment.adapter;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.example.onboardingfold.fragment.OnboardingPage1Fragment;
import com.example.onboardingfold.fragment.OnboardingPage2Fragment;

public class MyCustomFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    // for storing the total number of pages in the viewPager
    private static int NUM_PAGES = 2;

    public MyCustomFragmentPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that particular page
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show OnboardingPage1Fragment
                return OnboardingPage1Fragment.newInstance(1);
            case 1: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                return OnboardingPage2Fragment.newInstance(2);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

    // returns the width of the page
    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return super.getPageWidth(position);
    }
}
```